# Button to clear input value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button (`id="delete"`) that will clear any text entered in my field (`id="input"`), I have made a function and button, however after pressing the button nothing happens. Can't find the issue, the console also doesn't give any errors. Will be thankful for your assistance.

HTML:

```html
<span contenteditable="true" ><p id="input"></p></span>
<button  id="delete">Delete Data</button>
```

JS:

```
const trigger = document.getElementById("delete");
trigger.value = '';
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: So where is your event listener for the click??

Comment: Why are you setting the value of the button? Contenteditable also does not have a value.

Comment: You shouldn't have tags nested inside contenteditable fields. They'll be overwritten when you edit.

Comment: So `id="input"` should be on the editable element, not an element inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take action when a button is clicked, you should listen for its "click" event.

```
document.querySelector("#delete").addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = ''
})
```

Comment: `const trigger = ` makes no sense